# Cannot instantiate IdentityDbContext passing an instance of SqlConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, asp.net-identity

I am struggluing to get my entity framework IdentityDbContext to work with an existing instance of SqlConnection. Basically, I have:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {

private static DbCompiledModel CreateDbCompiledModel()
        {
            //if (_compiledModel != null) return _compiledModel;
            using (var context = new KmContext())
            {
                var internalProp = typeof (DbContext)
                    .GetProperty("InternalContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var internalContext = internalProp.GetValue(context);
                var modelBeingInitProp = internalContext.GetType().GetProperty("CodeFirstModel");
                var model = (DbCompiledModel) modelBeingInitProp.GetValue(internalContext);
                return (_compiledModel = model);
            }
        }

public MyContext(SqlConnection conn):base(conn, base(existingConnection, CreateDbCompiledModel(), false)
{

}
//...
}
```

Since IdentityDbContext hides the constructor DbContext(DbConnection,bool) (an open issue - https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/1991), I need to use the constructor DbContext(DbConnection, DbCompiledModel, bool), which is exposed by IdentityDbContext by the constructor used in the above code. The problem is that passing a valid instance of DbCompiledModel is far from trivial, as it can be seen in the static method CreateDbCompiledModel(). Furthermore, this code does not work, for I am having the exception "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."

I need to make it work, but I am out of cards right now. Can anyone help me?